# What are the best online platforms to hire a quant?

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, trading

I have already written the base of a trading algorithm, however there are some optimisations that I would like to add that might be best programmed by more experienced quantitative programmers.

This could be done in pseudo code or ideally in C#.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because quant recruitment is not on-topic.